# The Majority of Unix tools are written in what programming language?

Tags: c, linux, bash, unix, grep

Here is an example of using two Unix tools:

```
ls | grep "MMC"
```

`ls` and `grep` are two Unix tools.

I believe that both `ls` and `grep` are written in C. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

What programming language is used to implement modern-day Unix tools? Are modern-day Unix tools still implemented in C? Or, are other languages used?

Comment: `GNU Parallel` and `Exiftool` are written in Perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unix tools are written in a number of languages. Most of the classic tools are written in languages such as C and C++, but Perl and Python are also popular choices. C is still the dominant language, but it seems that Go might find some use in writing Unix command-line utilities.

Comment: Not to mention that Perl and (the most common implementation of) Python are also written in C.  Heck, even C itself is written in C. ;)

Comment: @lcd047: To be precise, most *implementations* of C are written in C. There's no fundamental reason another language couldn't be used. In particular, gcc is in the process of migrating from C to C++ (I don't know the current status of the migration).

Answer (score 4):

UNIX was originally written by Ken Thompson and Dennis Ritchie in assembly language, but soon migrated it to Thompson's C language. Early UNIX's kernel, shell, filesystem and basic utilities were all written in C, and this is true of all the UNIX flavors of which I know today.

However, not everything is written in C (that would be a pain). A powerful feature of UNIX is its shell, every flavor of which (sh, bash, csh, tcsh ksh, zsh, …) has automation via scripting. Some “UNIX tools” are implemented by sewing together other compiled tools in a shell script.

Other tools are implemented similarly to shell scripts, but executed by other scripting languages such as perl or python. Python is quite popular lately, being used even to write front-end graphical programs that an early UNIX programmer would never have dreamed of being written in an interpreted scripting language.

C++ is less common in UNIX because of tradition and C's momentum. C++ also requires a separate C++ standard library to be installed. A UNIX system can get along just fine without ever coming in contact with C++ or it's standard library. A major exception to this is GCC, because versions after 4.8 are built with c++.

See Also:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23635/106703
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/242832
- http://www.quora.com/What-programming-language-are-operating-systems-written-in

Comment: GCC switched internally to C++ with [version 4.8](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-4.8/changes.html). (4.0 was back in 2006.)